# Opening multiple mdDialog boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Is there a way to keep two mdDialog boxes open one on top of another or one coming from an event fired inside another in angular material design implemenation ? The current scenario which I am implementing is one mdDialog open on a click inside which another event is fired. but when the second mdDialog popus up , the first one automatically disappears. Is there an exisiting solution to this one ? i am using the first version of angular material

Comment: Which version do you use exactly? Is it possible to upgrade to the latest (master)?

Comment: The version of angular material i am using right now is "angular-material": "~0.11.2",

Comment: In that case it's probably impossible to do it.

Comment: is there any upgrade in the versions later to the one i am using ?

Comment: Latest is 1.1.0-rc4. That still wouldn't be enough though. But! If you could grab the latest master from Github and build that, you would be able to use `mdPanel` and with that it's possible what you want to achieve.

Comment: can you give me some more idea how to implement that functionality ?

Comment: You can check it out here: https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/panel

Comment: Thank you very much for the help i will check this out. Also are you aware of the md-select not working properly in tablets issue ? when i open the broweser in dev tools and emulate the ipad or tablet mode , the md-select input dropdown is not working i am really clicking hard for 1 send and then it opens and goes away unlike working like a normal drop down on touch. Can you help me with this ? is this also related to the angular material version ?

Comment: You can try it out here: https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/select and then compare it with your version. As I can see in 0.11.4 you have to touch for a bit to get it open. In the latest version it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can open multiple dialogs by passing the option skipHide: true

```
let alert = this.$mdDialog.alert({
    content: 'stuff',
    skipHide: true
})
$mdDialog.show(alert);
$mdDialog.show(alert);
```

You should have two dialogs open now. You might need to play around with the css to get the z-index right.